# Custom marker info for google map V3 andorid sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I work on android google map sdk v3.

And I would like to create a custom info box like the below:

[image]

[image]

The problem is , all I found online source is about V2 , like this:

http://topandroidphones1.blogspot.hk/2013/01/custom-infowindowadapter-with-dynamic.html

http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.hk/2012/12/using-infowindowadapter-part-1.html

I wonder is the google map v3 is support the infoWindowAdapter? or using other way to create the custom info box? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Version 3 of Google Maps API for Android.

Version 2 is the current version and all documentation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/